# Docker with different kernels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, docker

I'm wondering how Docker can run RHEL)(2.6) on a debian host (assume docker run on Debian latest kernel 3.x kernel). How this dockers layering approach work here.As far as i knoW docker is  using a concept called OS-level virtualization. So it adds layers or rings to the base image. but how it work with different kernel versions? and will there by any performance degradation  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, docker is available only as part of RHEL7 onwards, (not sure about Debian). Linux Containers involves things like resource management, process isolation, and security. Some of the features use cgroups, namespaces, and SELinux which were already available earlier IMHU. Docker basically automates the deployment of applications inside these Containers, and provides the capability to package the runtime dependencies into a container.